# How to optimize CSS styles?

Tags: css, optimization, styles

I need to optimize CSS styles using property cursor: pointer just one time. But there are different rules for different cases. How I can do it? Please, do you have any ideas, guys?

```
    .product {
  &.grid .grid-product__text:not(._price),

  &.grid .grid-product__text._price,

  &.grid .grid-product__text .grid-product__text_inner {
    color: inherit !important;
  }

  &._photo-name-transition {
    ._name,
    ._image {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  &._name-transition {
    ._name {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  &._photo-transition {
    ._image {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the selector `[class$="foo"]` that will select every item that have a class finishing by "foo".

So, in your case, this is the global idea.

```
&[class$="-transition"] {
    ._name,
    ._image {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

If you understand the selector I pointed you, you should be able to optimize your code if my solution isn't exactly right, good luck!

More info here : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp